# How can I access socket through Openshift

Tags: php, sockets, https, openshift, mosquitto

I register in the Openshift.com and create a catridge. But when I need to deploy Mosquitto, a MQTT Server, which is accessed through tcp or ssl protocol, and I need visit from public IP.
**Does Openshift just redirect http/https protocol through  80/443 port to 8080?** 
Is it possible to use socket communcation in Openshift?

I have created two applications in Openshift, one for push and the other for web deployment, and I stopped the apache service in order to let the mosquitto service listen to 8080. But only if I send post request in https protocol, It can access to the server for a while and disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might point you in the right direction https://www.openshift.com/blogs/paas-websockets.

Comment: This provides a new train of thought for me,I need to make a keep-alive connection between the client and the server,but the openshift only redirect the http packet through 80 or 443 port.I will try it.3Q.

Answer (score 0):

To save some readings from the readers, the steps involved in niharvey's answer:

- Create a diy app in your openshift account.
- Git checkout the code.
- Add a websocket app of your own choice that would bind to `$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP:$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT`.
- Modify the action hooks for starting and stopping your app. Push the code.
- From the client, connect to port `8000` for `ws://` or `8443` for `wss://`, by your app url.

Just verified these steps do work as expected.

Comment: Your own websocket app could be a compiled mosquitto.

Comment: I'm asking a question about the exact steps to get mosquitto to run on openshift here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383603/how-to-run-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-on-openshift-online .