# How to connect to my MQTT Broker in Openshift

Tags: openshift, mqtt, jbossfuse

Following these two tutorials (https://www.anavi.org/article/182/ and http://wei-meilin.blogspot.tw/2014/05/red-hat-openshift-xpaas-simple-mqtt.html) I have installed a MQTT Broker using JBoss Fuse.

Although my mqtt-container disappears after a while (I don't know why) I can make a port-forwarding and test the broker.

**But I would like to know how to connect directly to the broker. Do you know how to do it?**

I have tried this tutorial (http://training.runcloudrun.com/advanced/16-Network-and-Protocols.md.html - AMQ Example) but I don't have access to "/var/lib/openshift/.httpd.d/sniproxy.cfg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Online Openshift and that feature is [only available for Enterprise edition](https://developers.openshift.com/en/xpaas-fuse.html#availability).

Why  doesn't Openshift have this feature (complete) in the Online mode?

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the first tutorial that you pointed out. If you want to use MQTT without local port forwarding please have a look at the remark at the article on my blog and the AMQ cartridge that demonstrates the SNI features:

> The port forwarding is not convenient for real life cases, especially if the MQTT clients are working on embedded devices such as microcontrollers and it is recommended to use a SNI Proxy as explained here: http://training.runcloudrun.com/advanced/16-Network-and-Protocols.md.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

I only wanted to use the MQTT broker as a normal broker where I can directly connect to it without any other configuration in the client.

Comment: In this case I recommend you to use a cloud hosting with a container from kyup.com or to use cloudmqtt.com. I plan to share my experience with both services on my personal blog in near future.

Comment: I will follow you the.

Comment: As promised I have recently published a tutorial how to create a Linux container with cloud hosting from Kyup, to install the open source MQTT broker Mosquitto and to connect directly to it without any other configuration in the client: https://www.anavi.org/article/183/

Comment: Very very interesting. This can be use in a real environment. Besides, I didn't know about Kyup and I am going to give them a try. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around is to use the mqtt over websocket feature with a DIY cartridge. See the SO question "[How can I access socket through Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37065463/362754)" for some pointers to further details about how to run websocket on openshift.

The [mosquitto](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto) seems to have implemented the websocket feature though I have not verified by testing it out.

Comment: I've got mosquitto mqtt broker running on openshift with one source code patch. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383603/how-to-run-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-on-openshift-online