# How to run mosquitto mqtt broker on openshift online

Tags: websocket, openshift, mqtt, mosquitto

Has anybody successfully run [mosquitto](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto) on the [openshift online version in a free account](https://www.openshift.com/)?

There are two SO questions relevant but not really solve all the questions:

- ["How to connect to my MQTT Broker in Openshift"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973608/how-to-connect-to-my-mqtt-broker-in-openshift). It runs JBoss Fuse and needs either the SNI feature on the server or the port-forwarding on the client.
- ["How can I access socket through Openshift"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654119/how-can-i-access-socket-through-openshift/37065463#37065463). The author mentions running mosquitto but there is no details as to how.

Stuffs that have been done so far:

- I have run a python websocket server thus to have verified openshift does support websocket nicely though the DIY cartridge.
- I have also compiled mosquitto and run it locally with [a sample](http://jpmens.net/2014/07/03/the-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-gets-websockets-support/) [off github](https://github.com/jpmens/simple-mqtt-websocket-example).

What is the exact steps to put mosquitto to run on the openshift from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working on openshift, though with a simplest configuration. Here is the key steps:

- Use an openshift `DIY` cartridge to get the websocket support which exposes external port `8000` and that is routed to internal port `8080` on an virtual IP address specified by `OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP`.
- Compile mosquitto with all the following features turned off in `config.mk` just to avoid installing lot of packages to openshift: `WITH_TLS`, `WITH_TLS_PSK`, `WITH_THREADING`, `WITH_BRIDGE`, `WITH_SRV`, `WITH_UUID`, `WITH_DOCS`, `WITH_SOCKS`.
- Modify the `Makefile` of mosquitto to comment out the command to install from `DOCSDIR`. This seems to be a minor bug in mosquitto because if the `WITH_DOCS` is turned off it should not try to install from `DOCSDIR`.
- Turn on `WITH_WEBSOCKETS` in `config.mk`.
- Modify the file `src/webockets.c`. In the function `mosq_websockets_init()` at about line 625, add a line of `info.iface = listener->host;`, below the line which is `info.user = user;`. This is to make mosquitto able to bind to the virtual IP address in the openshift DIY gear. By default mosquitto only allow you to bind to `0.0.0.0` for any IP address. This seems to be a disconnection between mosquitto and libwebosockets.
- Install `libwebsockets` and `libwebsockets-devel` packages.
- Run `make` to build mosquitto.
- Lets assume you want to install mosquitto to `../mosrun` directory. Create the directory. Run `make prefix=  DESTDIR=$(pwd)/../mosrun install`.
- Delete all folders under `../mosrun` except `sbin`. `cd ../mosrun/sbin` and `cp /usr/lib/libwebsockets.so.7 .`. Adjust the source path of your stock libwebsockets lib.
- Grab all the files from `https://github.com/jpmens/simple-mqtt-websocket-example`. Put them into your `mosrun/sbin/simpleweb` directory.
- Modify `mosrun/sbin/simpleweb/config.js` to use your openshift DIY domain name, and port 8000. This is where the javascript connects to your DIY server from a browser.
- Create a mosquitto configuration file `mosrun/sbin/mosquitto.conf` which contains four lines: `listener 8080 <OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP>`, `protocol websockets`, `http_dir simpleweb`, and `connection_messages`. Use your actual DIY virtual IP address in place of `<OPENSHIFT_DIY_OP>`.
- Copy the whole tree to your openshift DIY gear.
- Browse with a browser to your DIY domain from a browser so you'll see the default server page.
- Modify openshift `.openshift/action_hooks/start` and `.../stop` scripts to comment out the existing commands. Push to openshift. Now you should not be able to connect to the default server but the gear is running.
- Go into your mosquitto `mosrun/sbin` directory.
- Run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf -v` to start mosquitto.
- Browse to your `diy-yourdomain.rhcloud.com:8000/index.html`. You shall see the mqtt websockets test page copied from jpmen's github repo.

The next step would be to move the tree into DIY git tree. Modify the start and stop hooks to start and stop your mosquitto instead of the default server. And a script running on the openshift gear to create the `config.js` and `mosquitto.conf` from the actual openshift environment variables.

Tow posts are very helpful to guide you through the steps of building mosquitto: [the blog by jpman](http://jpmens.net/2014/07/03/the-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-gets-websockets-support/), and [the blog by Jeremy Gooch](http://goochgooch.co.uk/2014/08/01/building-mosquitto-1-4/).

Comment: mosquitto 1.4.9 was released yesterday with the fix of `info.iface = listener->host;` so you don't need to manually patch the source code. the github fixes branch contains this patch. other branches do not yet.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs across this post; I have a non-websocket Mosquitto running on OpenShift v3.11:  https://github.com/john2exonets/OpenShift-MQTT-Mosquitto